# ¿Cómo mostrar la hora a tiempo real en reloj digital?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un reloj digital en Python pero lo que quiero es que muestre la hora actual real por ventana y no sé cómo hacerlo, ¿sabrían cómo ayudarme? Gracias.

De momento esto es lo que llevo:

```py
import time
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Reloj")
wn.bgcolor("SlateGray3")
wn.setup(700, 400)
turtle.hideturtle()
style = "Courier", 30

h = 0
m = 0
s = 0

while True:

    wn.update()

    s = str(s)
    m = str(m)
    h = str(h)

    turtle.write("  "+s+"s", font=style, align="left")
    turtle.write(m+"m", font=style, align="center")
    turtle.write(h+"h  ", font=style, align="right")

    s = int(s)
    m = int(m)
    h = int(h)

    s += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if s >= 60:
        s = 0
        m += 1
        if m >= 60:
            m = 0
            h += 1

    turtle.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Reloj")
wn.bgcolor("SlateGray3")
wn.setup(700, 400)
turtle.hideturtle()
style = "Courier", 30

h = time.strftime("%H")
m = time.strftime("%M")
s = time.strftime("%S")

while True:

wn.update()

s = str(s)
m = str(m)
h = str(h)

turtle.write("  "+s+"s", font=style, align="left")
turtle.write(m+"m", font=style, align="center")
turtle.write(h+"h  ", font=style, align="right")

s = int(s)
m = int(m)
h = int(h)

s += 1
time.sleep(1.0)
if s >= 60:
    s = 0
    m += 1
    if m >= 60:
        m = 0
        h += 1

turtle.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Respetando tu propio código, con estas modificaciones podrás mostrar la hora en tiempo real, utilizando `strftime` de `time`:

```
import time
from time import strftime
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Reloj")
wn.bgcolor("SlateGray3")
wn.setup(700, 400)
turtle.hideturtle()
style = "Courier", 30

while True:
    wn.update()
    turtle.write(strftime('%Hh %Mm %Ss'), font=style, align="right")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    turtle.clear()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]